# Margin in container which apply it all children in android

Tags: android

Suppose I have a container like LinearLayout and it has 10 Element(TextView,editText,..etc), so I want to give top margin on each element inside linear layout. But I don't want to give margin individual each element, I want give top Margin to container ( LinearLayout) which apply to its all element . is it possible in android?

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout layout = yourLayout;
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use paddingTop in LinearLayout but I m not sure.
Try This in your XML file

---

android:paddingTop="10dp"

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but...
For vertical `LinearLayout` and `layout_marginTop` you only need to set it to the first children.

For horizontal `LinearLayout` and `layout_marginTop` (or any property that is relative to the parent and not a sibling element), you need an additional layout as child with the `layout_marginTop` value, another `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` for example.